# Как внутри работает инициализация List в C++?

Tags: c++, list

Есть класс Test с "говорящими конструкторами". С помощью него проверяю, когда создаются и уничтожаются экземпляры класса:

```
class Test {
    
public:
    Test()
    {
        cout << "Test hello" << endl;
    }

    ~Test() 
    {
        cout << "Test bye" << endl;
    }
```

И, соответственно, майн:

```
int main()
{
Test a, b, c;
   list<Test> lst{ a,b,c };
   cout << "\nlist size 1: " << lst.size() << endl;
   lst.remove(Test());
   cout << "\nlist size 2: " << lst.size() << endl;
}
```

Вывод такой:

> Test hello
> Test hello
> Test hello
> Test bye
> Test bye
> Test bye
> list size 1: 3
> Test hello
> Test bye
> Test bye
> Test bye
> Test bye
> list size 2: 0
> Test bye
> Test bye
> Test bye

Почему когда я добавил элементы в лист, вызвались деструкторы, но сами объекты не удалились? Почему в методе Remove() тоже вызвались деструкторы, но объекты снова не удалились, а так и остались до конца блока? Объясните, пожалуйста, как работает list внутри. Я делал отладку с заходами, но не понял организации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте разбирать по строкам:

1. Строка `Test a, b, c;` создает 3 обьекта класса `Test` и выводит строки

```
Test hello
Test hello
Test hello
```

2. В строке `list<Test> lst{ a,b,c };` обьекты из п. 1 копируются в `initializer_list`, а из него в сам список (Вы этого не видите, т.к. конструктор копирования ничего не выводит) и удаляются из `initializer_list`, что Вы и видите в строках

```
Test bye
Test bye
Test bye
```

3. После вывода размера следует строка `lst.remove(Test());`, в которой есть создание обьекта (`Test()` - вызов конструктора), что Вы и видите в выводе

```
Test hello
```

4. Т.к. все три обьекта в списке эквивалентны аргументу `remove`, то они удаляются из списка. Мы это наблюдаем в выводе

```
Test bye
Test bye
Test bye
```

5. После этого удаляется обьект, который Вы передали в `remove`

```
Test bye
```

6. После второго вывода размера списка, функция `main` завершается и удаляет все обьекты, которые создала (Ваши обьекты `a`, `b` и `c`), что также наблюдается в выводе

```
Test bye
Test bye
Test bye
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Спасибо. Я добавил конструктор копирования в код, и теперь метод Remove(Test()) у меня вызывает просто один конструктор и один деструктор(видимо, операция с этим переданным ему Test()), а другие объекты удаляются теперь только после выхода из блока. То есть, в конце вызываются 6 деструкторов. Могли бы вы это объяснить, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Enesan Конструктор копирования и так у Вас был. Просто он ничего не выводил на экран. Могу предположить, что `remove` ничего не удалила, т.к. не нашла одинаковых обьектов. Какой размер списка после `remove`?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте

```
Test(const Test&)
{
    cout << "Test copy" << endl;
}
```

и посмотрите на вывод - https://ideone.com/sqCOax

Теперь понятнее?

Comment: Ага, то есть, она работает с копиями объектов. Спасибо большое.